# SemaphoreSlim doesn't queue concurrent requests and still allows double bookings

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, semaphore

I'm having issues using the SemaphoreSlim class in .NET Core (2.2) and hope someone can help.

I have an API method (AddBooking) which adds bookings to a database, this method includes 3 awaited repository AddAsync() methods which add data to 3 separate tables.

All of the guides/docs I've seen for this class have slightly different usages, but none seem to actually be queuing concurrent requests, resulting in double bookings.

When stepping through the code, the CurrentValue of the semaphore changes from 1 to 0 when a request is in progress, then back to 1 following the call to Release().

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _asyncLock;
_asyncLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1); // in the constructor

public async Task<BookingResponse> AddBooking(NewBooking newBooking)
        {
            await _asyncLock.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            try
            {
                if (!IsWithinBookingTimeframe(newBooking))
                    return new BookingResponse { Result = false, Message = "Bookings must be between 6am and 8pm" };

                AmendIfDayLightSavings(newBooking);

                var bookingDetailsResponse = await CreateBookingDetails(newBooking);
                if (!bookingDetailsResponse.Result)
                    return bookingDetailsResponse;

                var parkingSpaceBookingResponse = await CreateParkingSpaceBooking(newBooking, bookingDetailsResponse.BookingDetails);
                if (!parkingSpaceBookingResponse.Result)
                    return parkingSpaceBookingResponse;

                await _unitOfWork.Save();
                return new BookingResponse { Task = "AddBooking", Result = true, Message = "Booking added successfully", BookingDetails = bookingDetailsResponse.BookingDetails, ParkingSpaces = parkingSpaceBookingResponse.ParkingSpaces };
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return new BookingResponse { Task = "AddBooking", Result = false, Message = $"Error adding booking to database: {exception}" };
            }
            finally
            {
                _asyncLock.Release();
            }
        }
```

My understanding of this class is that if CurrentCount is 0, subsequent requests are queued until the semaphore is released and the CurrentCount is incremented to 1 (thus allowing the next task through), however making simultaneous requests still results in double bookings.

Comment: Should that `SemaphoreSlim` be `static`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call it like this: `_asyncLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);`

Because the first argument is the initial count and the second is the maximum count.
Now you only provided an initial count and after the first call to `Release()` you can call it without a limit.

Or in other words the second argument prohibits more than n concurrent calls.
The first argument means how many calls can be made before a first call to `Release()` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it! The things I read about the class seemed to imply that initialCount also acted as a maxCount if only one argument was provided :/.

Comment: @Tom I made the same mistake.

Comment: It's weird to me. I am looking at SemaphoreSlim source code and the only impact of MaxCount is the number of release you can do without acquire. Are you sure it solves your problem? https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/580152a50e4092d32c7d05ec876cd6976483ebf1/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs

Comment: @BrunoBelmondo Can you provide a link, because that seems backwards in relation to how I tested my SemaphoreSlim instance.

Answer (score 2):

Everything depends on where and who instantiate your asynclock. You probably have multiple instances of your class and each one have it's own lock which makes them not see the other request.

Basically you receive a request -> instantiate your class -> aquire lock -> generate booking

You have to make sure that the semaphore instance is shared between instances of your class which will run this code.

As a hint, insert a log/breakpoint into your class constructor. You will proably see it's instantiated more than once (and creating multiple semaphore)